# Regex to match alphanumeric string with letters, if present, to form at least one sequence of 3+ letters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, redux

This works wrong.
for example this is right - ddd, 2ddd, 2d2ddd, w4hh2www and 2dd, 2d2d2d, dd2d, dd2dd2dd2d this is a wrong, but its working not correctly,
`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{2}/ or /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{3}/`

Comment: It's unclear what you're after. Can you present us with specifics on what you're looking for? Are numbers allowed or no? Please give us examples of all valid and all invalid formats so that we better understand where you're stuck

Comment: in that value can be both, letters and numbers
but must be 3 letters next to each other
what is unclear??

Comment: I'm not alone in misunderstanding your question as two people have downvoted thus far. I'd suggest updating your question to provide us with full details. Even the answer that was provided to you doesn't help and was deleted because of confusion (since undeleted), you presented the person who answered your question with other examples

Comment: this is correct 2ddd, ddd, d2ddd54j, da9vid

this is incorrect d2d2d, 2dd, dd3, df44ff

Comment: @Ethan try `/.*[a-zA-Z]{3}.*/`

Comment: @Ethan or `/(?<=.*)[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=.*)/`

Comment: @Ethan : regarding valid samples in your latest comment, is it ***ALL*** letters should go in group of at least 3 or there should be at least one group of 3+ letters?

Comment: @Splitter's first method works if you're only looking for any lines with 3 alpha chars. `^[a-z\d]*[a-z]{3}[a-z\d]*$` should be used if the OP is looking for lines consisting of only alphanumeric characters and replacing `^` and `$` with `\b` if OP is looking for individual words

Comment: @Splitter your last example works in V8+ engines, but it would be simpler to just check if `[a-zA-Z]{3}` matches.

Comment: @ctwheels you're right about that simplification

Comment: should be at least one group of 3 letters

Comment: @Ethan now you have multiple options because your question is unclear.

Comment: my question : validation - can be numbers and letters, BUT at  least one group of 3  letters next to each other

Comment: /(?<=.*)[a-zA-Z]{3}(?=.*)/

thank you, it works correctly

Comment: @Ethan : now you got me totally confused, as above accepts `',aaa'` as valid

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov yes, this is why this question need focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try that one: `/(^[a-z\d]*[a-z]{3}[a-z\d]*$)|(^\d+$)/i`

```js
const src = ['2ttt78','q6n','44aaa78','a8','!bbb9','9c','9ddd','2w2www','2d2d2d', '78'],

      pattern = /(^[a-z\d]*[a-z]{3}[a-z\d]*$)|(^\d+$)/i
      
      src.forEach(s =>
        console.log(`${s} is valid: `, pattern.test(s)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: in case of 2w2www it doesn't work

in value can be letters and numbers, but at least 3 letters next to each other

Comment: i think somethink like this /^([a-z0-9]*[a-z]){3}[a-z0-9]*$/i

but theres a issue , 2d2d2d matches to this regex, but its wrong value

Comment: (2w2www) its must be valid value

Comment: Using `i` you don't need `a-zA-Z`

Comment: @Ethan : note, I have applied the quick fix for 'numbers-only' type of string